# how can i show only updated records in history page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a table user. In user table there may be many users like XYZ,ABC etc.

and columns of user are id,name,age,phoneno,emailid,address.

Now I have three pages login.php,profile.php and history.php.

Now when user **XYZ** login in his account **(User XYZ has his id and password)**. Then in profile page there are some editable text fields like name,age,phone number,emailid **(Email id is unique not editable)** and address.

Now user XYZ changes his phone number and address. Then only updated phone number and address must be shown in history page of user XYZ **(like User XYZ changed his phone number 123456... and address abcdefgh..)**.

How it can be possible. Please help as soon as possible.

Comment: it depends on your logic. you need to maintain a separate DB table where you can save the type of change made by user and created date.  Just sort the table according to date and show in history table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about audit log or audit trail. There are many ways to do it depending on your preference.

What I've encounter is to put status on the table, date updated and who updated the data.

Then I need to compare the previous record and new record and find which field changes.

The other way is you have a table that will store the field changes. Everytime there is a change on you table you will save the action on the table, field changed, date changed and who did the changes.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: how to compare the previous record and new record. is any query. Please help.

Comment: I do it in program logic. select all fields then compare each field. then when I got the difference, I'll display it.